# what is the bash command-line to connect to a network?

Tags: linux, bash

I am working in Linux/unix sh shell. I am following instructions to download data from a repository which consist of two mirrored systems. 
Instructions say I must be able to make a http (Port 80) connection to both systems (or at least one) in order to download the data. What bash command-line should I use?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd say `nmap` is the best option here, since it gives a clear answer:

```
sudo nmap -sS -p80 <ip address>
```

The output is either something like

```
Host is up (0.027s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http
```

or, in the negative case

```
Host is up (0.024s latency).
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
80/tcp filtered http
```

---

That is something you can easily pipe into a grep command:

```
sudo nmap -sS -p80 xx.xx.xx.xx | grep "/tcp"
```

This will result in either

```
80/tcp open  http
```

or

```
80/tcp filtered http
```

Comment: OP needed to download data.  Netcat, wget, or curl.

Answer (score 2):

Use wget :
wget http://url/file.tar.gz
or if you want to check if port 80 is really open on the host , simply use telnet :

telnet server_ip 80
you should get some kind of reply. If no HTTP service running , you will get 'connection refused'